# Python copying a folder many times

Tags: python, copy, directory, rename, shutil

I'm writing a code which asks the user to enter an input for copying a folder ..
I want the code to get the number of times from the user then start copying the folder and rename it like a series like that :

```
How many times you want to copy folder "moh"?
5
```

then create 5 copies of the folder named ( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 )

```
progs = int(raw_input( "Progs Number : "))
fullPath = currentDirectory + str(name)
if os.path.isdir( fullPath ):
    # Directory name is legitimate and not already existent
    shutil.rmtree ( fullPath )
    os.mkdir( fullPath )
    shutil.copy(moh, )    # This where the code should do the copying process but I don't know how to make the process repeated by the user input and rename the folder
else:
    os.mkdir( fullPath )
```

Comment: Just write a loop, `for i in range(progs):`, and then in the loop, use `shutil.copy(moh, str(i+1))`. (Or maybe `os.path.join(fullPath, str(i+1))`?)

Comment: Looks like the perfect opportunity to use a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to do something N times, the way to do that is usually a loop over `range(n)`:

```
for i in range(progs):
```

Now, that `i` is a number from 0-4, and you want a pathname in `fullpath` with the string value of `i+1`, right? So, translate that English to Python:

```
    pathname = os.path.join(fullpath, str(i+1))
```

And now, you know what to copy to:

```
    shutil.copy(moh, pathname)
```

Comment: thanks @abarnert for your help , but i faced this error when executing the command "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'moh'" , while i am using this prog under windows

Comment: @MohammedAldaoudi: That's telling you that you don't have read access on the `moh` directory or something inside it. On Windows, there are two possible reasons for that: you may not have read permission on everything in the directory, or some other program may have some file in the directory open with an exclusive lock. If you want to debug further, you may want to consider using `os.walk` to recursively go through every file in the directory and try to `open` and `read` them and see which one fails.

Comment: first i want to let you know that i had to to use the code like this shutil.copy("moh", pathname) with the quotes because when i tried without them i faced NameError: name 'sipcli' is not defined .. Also I made sure that i make the read permissions .. I really don't know how to use os.walk . On the other hand the folder contains dll and exe files

Comment: @MohammedAldaoudi: `"moh"` in quotes means the literal filename will be `moh`. Without quotes, it means the filename will be whatever's in the variable named `moh`. I did the latter, because that's what your question does. I have no idea how you could get a `NameError` on something called `sipcli`, because there's no such variable anywhere in the example.

Comment: @MohammedAldaoudi: Second, if you don't know how to use `os.walk`, then read the docs. The examples are really simple; there's no way I can write you anything simpler. And if the folder contains DLL and EXE files, there's a very good chance they're exclusively locked; if one of those EXE files is currently running, or one of those DLL files is being used by any program that's currently running, you generally can't copy them.

Comment: I used this code to see what will happen`for root, dirs, files in os.walk("sipcli", topdown=False):
                for name in files:
                    open(os.path.join(root, name))` but nothing shown , I followed the tutorial in python

Comment: @MohammedAldaoudi :  abarnert has remarkable patience! Indeed no one can make it simpler. You need to do your part and learn. For a start, try search for `os.walk` in SO. You will find example like e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079465/error-in-using-os-path-walk-correctly

Comment: @MohammedAldaoudi: First, if you have a new problem, asking a new question instead of posting followups as comments usually works better for everyone. Meanwhile, try not just opening the files, but `read`ing from them to see if that raises anything.